# Quickchecking with a typeclass constraint and reporting the generated values?

Tags: haskell, testing, typeclass, quickcheck

I'm trying to do a property-based test for a chess game. I have set up the following typeclass

```
class Monad m => HasCheck m where                                                   
    isCollision :: Coord -> m Bool
```

which checks if a given coordinate contains a collision or out of bounds.

Now I have a function that generates the moveset of allowed actions for a knight like the following

```
collisionKnightRule :: HasCheck m => Coord -> m (Set Coord)                      
collisionKnightRule =                                                            
    Set.filterM isCollision . knightMoveSet                                      


-- | Set of all moves, legal or not                                              
knightMoveSet :: Coord -> Set Coord                                              
knightMoveSet (x,y) =                                                            
    Set.fromList                                                                 
        [ (x+2,y-1),(x+2,y+1),(x-2,y-1),(x-2,y+1)                                
        , (x+1,y-2),(x+1,y+2),(x-1,y-2),(x-1,y+2)                                
        ]                                                                        



knightMoves :: HasCheck m => Coord -> m (Set Coord)                              
knightMoves pos =                                                                
    do  let moveSet =                                                            
                knightMoveSet pos                                                
        invalidMoves <- collisionKnightRule pos                                        
        return $ Set.difference moveSet invalidMoves
```

and an instance for the HasCheck class for an arbitrary coordinate

```
instance HasCheck Gen where                                                      
    isCollision _ =                                                              
         Quickcheck.arbitrary
```

and so afterwards to test this I want to ensure that the generated moveset is a proper subset of all possible moves.

```
knightSetProperty :: Piece.HasCheck Gen                                          
    => (Int,Int)                                                                 
    -> Gen Bool                                                                  
knightSetProperty position =                                                     
    do  moves <- Piece.knightMoves position                                      
        return $ moves `Set.isProperSubsetOf` (Piece.knightMoveSet position)

-- ... later on

it "Knight ruleset is subset" $                                          
            quickCheck knightSetProperty
```

Of course this fails because it could be that the knight can't move anywhere, which would mean that it's not a proper subset but the same set. However the error reported is not particularly helpful

```
*** Failed! Falsifiable (after 14 tests and 3 shrinks):  
(0,0)
```

This is because quickcheck doesn't report the generated value of isCollision. Therefore I wonder, how can I make quickCheck report the generated value of `isCollision`?

Comment: Why does `HasCheck` involve a `Monad m`? Why do you even need that type class? Wouldn't it be simpler to have a pure function `isCollision :: Coord -> Bool`, without involving a type class?

Comment: For the knight it's not so interesting but the pawn depends on the state of the game and if it has moved before therefore it needs to be a Monad for the State Monad.

Comment: Could you write the function as `Coord -> State s Bool` then? With an unconstrained `Monad m`, `m` could also be `[]`, `IO`, `->`, `Maybe`, and all sorts of other monads. Are any of those meaningful?

Comment: The `(->)` instance of HasCheck is used for mocking in unit tests. Potentially `IO` could be interesting too if it's instead requesting a server.  The reason I implemented it that way was that I didn't want the logic for the Pieces to concern itself in anyway about how the board is implemented. In theory quickcheck shouldn't need to care about the state of the board either.

Comment: One usually doesn't mock in FP; there's no need, because [pure functions are already intrinsically testable](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2015/05/07/functional-design-is-intrinsically-testable). Could you design the code so that it's composed of pure functions instead?

Comment: The Piece module implements all the logic for the pieces without depending on state. We still need a way to check if a coordinate is a collision or not. By abstracting it away in a type class HasCheck we can instance it in a stateless way. All HasCheck constrainted functions work if given a isCollision function, separating logic from implementation. It's inescapable that this function will depend on state for the real implementation but we can move that stateful implementation to the outward of the program, leaving the core testable, pure and stateless. So in that sense we "mock" isCollision.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190675/discussion-between-marc-and-mark-seemann).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so I feel this should be solvable in another way. However I made the following solution that works inspired by the [handler pattern](https://jaspervdj.be/posts/2018-03-08-handle-pattern.html).

I changed the HasCheck typeclass to a record, as follows:

```
data Handle = MakeHandle                                                                   
    { isCollision   :: Coord -> Bool                                                   
    }
```

and then refactored all the code to use handle instead of HasCheck.

```
collisionKnightRule :: Handle -> Coord -> (Set Coord)                            
collisionKnightRule handle =                                                     
    Set.filter (isCollision handle) . knightMoveSet                              


-- | Set of all moves, legal or not                                              
knightMoveSet :: Coord -> Set Coord                                              
knightMoveSet (x,y) =                                                            
    Set.fromList                                                                 
        [ (x+2,y-1),(x+2,y+1),(x-2,y-1),(x-2,y+1)                                
        , (x+1,y-2),(x+1,y+2),(x-1,y-2),(x-1,y+2)                                
        ]                                                                        


-- | Set of illegal moves                                                        
knightRuleSet :: Handle -> Coord -> (Set Coord)                                  
knightRuleSet =                                                                  
    collisionKnightRule                                                          


knightMoves :: Handle -> Coord -> (Set Coord)                                    
knightMoves handle pos =                                                         
    let                                                                          
        moveSet =                                                                
            knightMoveSet pos                                                    

        invalidMoves =                                                           
            knightRuleSet handle pos                                             
    in                                                                           
        Set.difference moveSet invalidMoves
```

The disadvantage of this is I fear that for stateful code it can be easy to introduce an error where you pass in a handle that is out-of-date,  I.E. having multiple sources of truths. An advantage is that this is probably easier for people new to Haskell to understand. We can now mock functions using the Quickcheck's Function  typeclass and pass them as an argument to make a mockHandler:

```
knightSetProperty ::                                                                 
    Fun (Int,Int) Bool                                                               
    -> (Int,Int)                                                                     
    -> Gen Bool                                                                      
knightSetProperty (Fun _ isCollision) position =                
    let                                                                              
        handler = 
            Piece.MakeHandle isCollision                           
        moveSet =                                                                      
            Piece.knightMoves handler position                                       
    in                                                                               
        return $ moveSet `Set.isProperSubsetOf` (Piece.knightMoveSet position)
```

Now this fails properly with a counterexample:

```
*** Failed! Falsifiable (after 53 tests and 74 shrinks):     
{_->False}
(0,0)
```